# Sync audio -Harmonics of sync (not frequency)

Tags: sync, frequency, fundamental

I'm clocking in some freebie hours, re-aligning audio for a project that was butchered with plural eyes program and I'm seeing patterns of sync that remind of of the harmonics after a Fundamental Frequency and I was wondering if people have any comments on experiences you've had like this.
It seems to me that before and after the exact sync point between audio and video (image) (i'm using samples)  there are certain points that seem in a rythm or a correct harmonic disposition to it.

Comment: As a comment, I wanted to comment about a sync trick/idea that just popped into my head.  When you are out of sync, just a little bit, what is really happening (with dialogue at least) is the audience is hearing things twice!  the audio says things at one time and the image says the same thing but not at the same time!  It's kind of like a psychological haas delay?!

Comment: re sync dialogue, when its late it is less annoying than when its early, I guess because in reality sound is never early whereas with distance sound IS late... early dialogue just looks so wrong!

Answer (score -1):

DSLRs are notoriously bad at keeping sync. Even the internal audio is like 1-2 frames off. I've also had that experience... Especially the Canon 5D Mark IIs with the old firmware. I work in sweden so our video is always 25 fps.. with the old 5D MKII you could only shoot in 30fps so you had to convert the video after shooting and there'd always be sync issues.

Have never used Plural eyes, don't really know what it is, but am I right if it's a software for autosyncing? I wouldn't trust it a bit if it is.

Good luck!